# how to get the hibernate mysql database connection to android emulator

Tags: android, hibernate, struts2

I am new to Android development. How can I connect to a MySQL web server database in the Android emulator?
My web application database is connected via hibernate in a struts2 application. Please help me and send some code for struts and Android.

Comment: This is a duplicate of an earlier question you asked the day before.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide much detail so it's not really possible to help you but here are a few thoughts. If your application is a web application you don't connect directly to MYSql through Android, you need to talk to the web server. You can do this in several ways either having the user use the normal site through the browser on Android, create a special version of the site optimized for mobile devices that the user would access through Android's browser, or using web services. If you want to create an Android application instead of having the user use the actual site on their device you'll need to research web services, any functionality requiring database access such as adding a record or listing records will then need to be exposed through web services and called from your Android app.

Comment: actually our web application developed by struts2.
mysql database connection get through hibernate via using tomcat server. we are like to access the data from database in android emulator.